# Best way to use a variable from Json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am creating a bit of code to take variables from php and show them with JavaScript i have used Json

```
{"ZW01001":[{"cycle":4051.23,"Percent":73.26}]}
```

what is the best way to then get the Cycle from the Json in to the cycle variable of the If statement also the Json_encoede result will have 14 arrays total so for example

```
{"ZW01004":[{"cycle":SomeValue,"Percent":SomeValue}]}
{"ZW01005":[{"cycle":SomeValue,"Percent":SomeValue}]}
```

and the part of the If statement for choosing the the element by Id should correspond to the ZW number at the start of each array

```
function Machinecycle(){
        var machines = <?PHP echo json_encode($Cycle); ?>

          if (cycle in machines < 480) {
            document.getElementById("ZL01001").style.backgroundColor = 'lime';
            document.write(Cycle);
        } else {
            document.getElementById("ZL01001").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output of Json_encode

```
{"ZW01001":{"0":{"cycle":4095.12,"percent":73.258823529412},"ZW01004":[{"cycle":5.95,"percent":-0.41661805150429}]}}
```

This is the output of var_dump($Cycle);

```
array(1) { ["ZW01001"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["cycle"]=> float(4097.15)        ["percent"]=> float(73.258823529412) } ["ZW01004"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["cycle"]=> float(7.98) ["percent"]=> float(-0.41661805150429) } } } }
```

This is the Php code, i have shortened it down to just 2 for ease use

```
$Cycle = array(

"ZW01001" => array(
array(
"cycle" => $machine1->Data(),
"percent" => $machine1->GetM()
),
"ZW01004" => array(
array(
"cycle" => $machine4->Data(),
"percent" => $machine4->GetM()
),
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if any of the elements have `cycle` less than `480`, you need to write a loop.

```
function Machinecycle(){
    var machines = <?PHP echo json_encode($Cycle); ?>

    for (var key in machines) {
        if (machines[key].cycle < 480) {
            document.getElementById(key).style.backgroundColor = 'lime';
            document.write(Cycle);
        } else {
            document.getElementById(key).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        }
    }
}
```

It also seems wrong to mix DOM functions and `document.write()`. What is the latter for?

Comment: http://imgur.com/7uQrosW There will be 14 blocks if you will {"ZW01001":[{"cycle":4051.23,"Percent":73.26}]}  would be the data for the first 
{"ZW01004":[{"cycle":4051.23,"Percent":73.26}]}  for the second and so on so i would need to check if cycle for ZW01001 is less than 480    and then change the background for each of the blocks based on there bit of data

Comment: Leaving this one for you :) Still think the JSON by PHP could be formatted to better fit.

Comment: @JoshKirkpatrick Do you really have an array of objects, where each object just has one property with a different key? Or is there one object whose keys are `ZW01001`, `ZW01004`, and so on? The second way would be a much better way to do it.

Comment: this is how i have the php array set up
$Cycle = array(
    
        "ZW01001" => array(
        array(
            "cycle" => $machine1->Data(),
            "Percent" => $machine1->GetM()
        
        )

Comment: Could you update the question and show what `var_dump($Cycle)` looks like? You're still not being clear about how the array of all 14 is set up.

Comment: I've updated my answer to match the corrected array.